# My Lambda is timeout with my S3 upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I didn't understand why my Lambda doesn't work with my csv upload.

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var json2csv = require('json2csv');

exports.handler = function (event, context) {

    AWS.config = {
        region: 'us-east-1',
        apiVersions : {
            s3: '2006-03-01'
        }
    };

    var s3 = new AWS.S3({signatureVersion: 'v4'});
    var bucket = 'search-dev'; 

    if(event.debug == true)
    {
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                            host     : event.database.host,
                            user     : event.database.user,
                            password : event.database.pwd,
                            database : event.database.name
                        });
    }

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
            context.fail(err);
        }
    });

    mysqlData();

    connection.end();

    function mysqlData () {
        connection.query('SELECT id, keywords, result_count FROM keyword WHERE result_count != ""', function (err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
                context.fail(err);
            }

            console.log(results.length + " trouvés");

            var csvFields = [];
            for (var i in fields) {
                csvFields.push(fields[i].name);
            }

            var csv = json2csv({ data: results, fields: csvFields });

            writeInFile(csv);
        });
    }

    function writeInFile(dataCsv)
    {
        filename = generateFilename();
        var params = {
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: filename+'.csv',
            Body: dataCsv
        };
        s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                context.fail(err);
            }

            context.succeed({url: data.Location});
        });

    }

    function generateFilename() 
    {
        var date = new Date();

        var filename = date.getDate()+'-'+date.getMonth()+'-'+date.getFullYear()+'_'+date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes()+':'+date.getSeconds();

        return filename;
    }

};
```

On other lambda function, there aren't a problem but here, it's all the time timeout with s3.upload my Lambda have S3FullAccess in IAM.

This code works perfectly in local.

And others problem is I created a new bucket but impossible to upload on it in local too `[NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist]` I don't understand because I created other bucket and they aren't a problem to upload on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you have placed the Lambda function inside your VPC. Once a Lambda function is placed inside the VPC it can only access resources inside the VPC. To give your Lambda function access to AWS resources outside your VPC, as well as access to the Internet, you need to [add a NAT Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) to your VPC.

Since you are only trying to access S3, there is a second option of [adding a S3 endpoint to your VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/).